# how can i access riak Kv by using my own developed rest Api using curl

Tags: riak

On same Remote Server I have to installed

1. Tomcat7.0
2. Riak kv

after that I set tomcat host as my Remote server IP,and riak host as localhost, then I am able to interact with riak using my Own Rest API.

for Example:

Through Postman:-

I am hitting Url :-
**http://localhost:8080/Apps/webapi/policy/savePolicy**

having body :-

**{
  "id": "1110007836",
  "policyDTOs": [
    {
      "policyNumber": "1000067730-12",
      "brandCode": null,
      "policystatus": null,
      "commencementDate": null,
      "issueDate": "16/04/2016",
      "endDate": "15/04/2017",
      "policyPeriod": null,
      "applicationNumber": "1000067730-12",
      "planOpted": "Easy Health Individual Standard",
      "planOptedCode": "11006",
      "riskStartDate": "16/04/2016",
      "riskEndDate": "15/04/2017",
      "policyId": null,
      "proposerName": "Ms Sonali Arora",
      "address": "330/4 Ram Nagar",
      "town": "Gurgaon",
      "district": null,
      "state": "Haryana",
      "country": "India",
      "pinCode": "122001",
      "emailId": "garimagauri@gmail.com",
      "mobile": "9958791166",
      "phoneFirst": null,
      "phoneSecond": null,
      "modeOfPayment": "Cheque/Cash-Dir",
      "loading": "0.00",
      "discount": 0,
      "grossPremium": 1751.34,
      "paymentMadeBy": null,
      "nomineeName": "MRS Asha Arora",
      "relationShipToPolicyHolder": "Mother",
      "dependents": [
        {
          "isExpired": null,
          "expiryDate": null,
          "lastRefreshTime": null,
          "keyValue": null,
          "createdDate": null,
          "modifiedDate": null,
          "memberId": "1110007837",
          "firstName": null,
          "middleName": null,
          "lastName": null,
          "fullName": "Ms Sonali Arora",
          "genderCode": null,
          "gender": "Female",
          "dependentBirthDate": null,
          "birthDate": "21/11/1984",
          "relationshipCode": null,
          "relationship": "Self",
          "sumInsuredForDependent": null,
          "sumInsured": null,
          "criticalIllinessRiderForDependent": null,
          "titleCode": null,
          "title": null,
          "clientCode": null,
          "maritalStatusCode": null,
          "nationalityCode": null,
          "annualIncome": null,
          "height": null,
          "weight": null,
          "productCode": 11108,
          "productType": null,
          "productName": null,
          "grossPremium": null,
          "sumInsuredForDependentStr": "100000",
          "dependentStatus": "Active",
          "sumAssuredCI": null
        }
      ],
      "policyClaimPeriod": "2012 - 2013",
      "sumInsuredFloater": "100000",
      "memberId": "1110007836",
      "fullPolicyNumber": "110103/11001/1000067730-02",
      "ciRiderFlag": false,
      "policyType": "RETAIL"
    }
  ],
  "policyExpired": false
}**

then saving this info with respect to its id.

now I want to save data by using curl command with same rest api, how can I do that,,,,,, I am not able to use curl command in this api to save the info.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the documents here: http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/developing/usage/creating-objects/

There are examples of using HTTP Post to write to Riak KV including:

```
curl -XPUT \
-H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
-d "vroom" \
http://localhost:8098/types/cars/buckets/dodge/keys/viper
```

Comment: I know this thing by using this I can save the data, but in a scenario, I have to find calculation, based on some Input, and I do in my own Rest API, using this how can I save fetched result which is returned by my API in RIAK KV bucket, and one more thing my API is developed with some Authorization key and AuthToken. I am able to access this by using POSTMAN, but I want to do using curl command.